# Vue - Import components in a multi-page environment

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wish to use Vue.js in a **multi-page environment**. For this project I can't use webpack or the vue.cli. I **have** to use basic ways of importing the various libraries and then using them. I'm nearly there but I can't figure out how I can import **components**. I'm assuming I need to use require.js but I don't know enough to proceed.

**This is the main component (index.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<title>Hello</title>
</head><body>

    <div id="app">
    <p>Hello this is the {{results}} app</p>

    <br /><br />

    <p>Now it's time for a component to be shown:</p>

    <app-my-accordion></app-my-accordion>

    </div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js'></script>
<script src='require.js'></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>

import MyAccordion from 'components/my-accordion.html'; // <--Problem here

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            'app-my-accordion': MyAccordion
        },
        data() {
            return {
                results: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get("http://myApi")
                .then(response => { this.results = response.data.name; console.log(response.data.name); })
        }
    });
</script>
</body></html>
```

**And then in my my-accordion.html**

```
<template>
<div>And my child's component name is: {{results}}</div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                results: null
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            axios.get("http://myOtherApi")
                .then(response => { this.results = response.data.name; console.log(response.data.name); })
        }
    }
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490627/how-to-do-import-export-a-class-in-native-javascript-code

Comment: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader