# Trigger a button from another button

Tags: javascript, html, button

i want to trigger a button's class by pressing another button. 
I got this button here

```
                 <button class="clear-cart banner-btn">clear cart</button>
```

which i am using to clear a cart. And i got this orderconfirmation html page, which i press "go back" button to go back to the home page and deleting the local storage. so when i return to the mainpage from orderconfirmation, i want my cart to be empty.

```
                        <button class="clear-cart banner-btn">clear cart</button>
```

of course i tried to put this code into the orderconfirmation page, but id didn't work. i even have the same javascript. So, is there anyway that when i click on a button from orderconfirmation page, it triggers the button in my cart in the main page? thanks in beforehand.

Comment: Something is really wrong, go back and fix it. If not then save the state in sessionstorage and when the site loads read from storage and clear the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like very bad practice to do what you want to do from the first part of the question. Why not just trigger the function? What I mean:

- You have button A that calls function A, and a button B.
- Why not have button B call the same function A? Or a function A2 that within itself calls the relevant parts or the whole function A)

As for how to have them connected - the second part of your question I'd say is much more on the good track - simply `import foo from 'path/to/foo'`? (If you have node set up). What's your setup, what are you using?

---

Why is it a bad practice? Separation of concerns. If you're not sure what that is, try checking out Clean Code or some similar guidance. Here's a good video by Uncle Bob (Clean Code) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dKZ-dWaCiU

E.g. Your problem is that you're thinking your cart is on the main page. It shouldn't be. It shouldn't be on a page. Page is a detail. You need the cart working regardless of any pages.

---

*This answer suppoes you're learning, not doing client work and therefore aim to understand over solving the direct problem.*

Here's a minimal (though not a very good) way to connect two files.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
    <body>
        <button>Button text</button>
    </body>
    <script src='./foo.js'></script>
</html>
```

```js
// foo.js
console.log('hi from foo')
```

What you need is functions available across pages, i.e. imported in every page. You could simply import it like this every time. Or check out frameworks to do it for you. **Be aware, frameworks are not the end all be all solutions**, though for learning, I guess they would set you on a good track.

---

The way to do it with modules (as linked to in the comment [How to do import/export a class in Vanilla JavaScript (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490627/how-to-do-import-export-a-class-in-vanilla-javascript-js)) is

```html
<script type="module" src="./foo.js"></script>
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Yes i do have a button A, and a button B. I set the function on the button B, but it's not working. that is why i wanted to know if there was a way trigger a button from another button. and no, i'm not using node. only html, css and vanilla javascript.

Comment: Try that import statement to a file that only has a console.log and see will it trigger. (e.g. `import foo from './foo.js' ` and in foo.js: `console.log('yep it's connected!')` Check the console from dev tools.

Comment: hello, i tried it. And i didn't see any logs. so it means that it's not connected or what? but i linked the javascript via html, i don't see any problem there.

Comment: Yeah. No logs, not connected. I've updated the answer with a minimal example, and also try checking the `module` attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490627/how-to-do-import-export-a-class-in-vanilla-javascript-js

Comment: thank you for the answer, i'll try to fix the problem with the link you've provided me.

Comment: *So this what you're doing is I suppose for learning, not a client project.* The point in connecting the scripts is that you will need some functions be always available, across pages. What you could do is simply attach it to `window` (e.g. with `window.foo = function foo {}` though that's bad practice (because they start to pile up and you'll end up overwriting them).

Comment: If my assumption this is for learning is correct - I'd recommend to go watch Unlce Bob (link from answer), regardless will it or won't go over your head - especially the part about frameworks - and then go watch tutorials on e.g. `vue.js`. That would solve your problem much better. Good luck :)