# Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to export variables from index.js to profile.js. When I export at the top of the file such as

```
export let k = 12;
```

Or

```
export { k }; let k = 12;
```

It works just fine. However, when I export after the DOMContentLoaded event such as

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ export let k = 12; })
```

then it shows *Unexpected token 'export'*. The one bellow is also gives the same error

```
if (true){ export let k = 2; }
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: the token export cannot be inside a function

Comment: You can't use `export` inside a function, because exporting happens as soon as the module is imported by some other module. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do import/export a class in Vanilla JavaScript (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490627/how-to-do-import-export-a-class-in-vanilla-javascript-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What should I do to be able to export variable after DOMContentLoaded

You can't. `export` and `import` can only appear at the *top level* of a module.

What you can do instead is export the variable, and set its value in the handler:

```
export let k;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ k = 12; })
```

If other modules import `k`, they get a *read-only binding* to it, meaning that if they use it before `DOMContentLoaded`, they'll get whatever initial value you provide (`undefined` in the above, because there's no initializer on the `let k;` declaration), but if they use it *after* the `DOMContentLoaded`, they'll see the value assigned by the handler.

That said, if your module provides information that is only available after a certain point, you might consider exporting a promise, like so:

```
let kPromiseResolve;
export const kPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    kPromiseResolve = resolve;
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ kPromiseResolve(12); })
```

Then modules using it would do:

```
import { kPromise } from "./your-module.js";
kPromise
.then(k => {
    //  ...use `k`...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...
});
```

or in environments supporting [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), if the importing module can't do anything useful without `k`, they could do:

```
import { kPromise } from "./your-module.js";
const k = await kPromise;
// ...use `k`...
```

Comment: *(Oops. In the first code block above, if you see `let k = 12;`, hit refresh. I forgot to remove the `let`.)*